# Counter for every item

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to make a cart page using the provider package and i wanted to have a quantity of every single item so every time i add a new product i want it to check if it exists in the list and if it exists i want it to count how many times it is added but if its not already in the cart it gets added to the cart

this is my `Cart` class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'item.dart';

class Cart extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<Item> items = [];
  double totalPrice = 0.0;
  int singleProductCount = 0;

  void add(Item item) {
      items.add(item);
      totalPrice += item.price;
      notifyListeners();
  }

  void remove(Item item) {
    items.remove(item);
    totalPrice -= item.price;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int get count {
    return items.length;
  }

  double get totalprice {
    return totalPrice;
  }

  int get singleproductCount {
    return singleProductCount;
  }

  List<Item> get basketItems {
    return items;
  }
}
```

and this is the `IconButton` that adds it to the cart

```
IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {
                                  cart.add(Item(name: snapshot.data.documents[index]["name"], price: snapshot.data.documents[index]["price"], imageUrl: snapshot.data.documents[index]["imageUrl"]));
                                }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a way, but hopefully, someone will have a better solution. But what I did was actually create another list to help us with the condition. This list will hold the names(or whatever you'd like it to hold). I then check if that name is in the list and if it is then it returns null, else add the *Item* into the list. This was the only way I could think of at the moment in the case when it comes to adding a class instance.

```
List<String> _names = [];
double totalPrice = 0.0;


List<String> get names {
  return _names;
  }



void add(Item item, String newNames) {
    itemList.add(item);
    _names.add(newNames); // add new names to names list
    totalPrice += item.price;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

> 

```
  // If the names list contains any name from the docs already, then don't add anything
  // else add the name to the list along with the Item
       cart.names.contains(snapshot.data.documents[index]["name"])
       ? null
       : cart.add(
        Item(
         name: snapshot.data.documents[index]["name"], 
         price: snapshot.data.documents[index]["price"],
         imageUrl: snapshot.data.documents[index]["imageUrl"]
        ),

         snapshot.data.documents[index]["name"]
     );
```

By the way, using *get* does not really make sense if you are not going to make your properties *private* by using an underscore, for example, int _singleProductCount = 0;

Comment: its saying it does not contain it everytime

Comment: and i tried to print a single item to see what it lookes like the item is `Instance of 'Item'`

Comment: I have updated my answer, hopefully, it will work for now.